# how to block the message box

Tags: html, css

We developing **chat application**. in that **input and out text message** is coming.but  **input and out put is coming side by side** but i **need one by one**.like if input is single later then that line total block then out put will come short or long text it should be come text line only but i am not able to getting that and **message box corners are coming different** any one please help me

This is we are facing please find screen shot

[image]

we need like this and corners are not coming same i need input user message how it is coming we need customer message box corner like that

[image]

```css
.userTextDiv {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 4px;
 clear: right;
}

.userTextDiv::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 right: -11px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDiv::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 right: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 8px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDiv img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.userTextDiv .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}

.userTextDiv .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 11px;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
 left: -18px !important;
 right: 0px !important;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 border: 14px solid transparent;
 border-top: 6px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
 left: -6px;
 right: 0px !important;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 4px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}
```

```html
<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, see my edited answer it solves both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to wrap the `message divs` in a new `div` with a `width:98%`.
so that new message comes after the first one.

**Thanks**

```css
.message-block{
  width:98%;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding:0px 10px;
}

.userTextDiv {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
  border-top:2px solid #999;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 4px;
 clear: right;
}

.userTextDiv::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -2px;
 right: -10px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDiv::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0.01em;
 right: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 10px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDiv img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.userTextDiv .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}

.userTextDiv .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 11px;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
left: -14px !important;
right: 0px !important;
content: '';
position: absolute;
visibility: visible;
top: -3px;
border: 11px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
left: -9px;
right: 0px !important;
content: '';
position: absolute;
visibility: visible;
top: -0.09em;
border: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 9px solid white;
clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-block">
<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="message-block">
<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="message-block">  
<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="message-block">
<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks Tanzil, it's working  and sorry Tanzil i am troubling you, i have one more problem message boxes corners is not coming same i need both same like user box how it is coming like that i need customer message box

Comment: you mean both messages `box` to have `corners` towards `right` ?

Comment: no corner shapes is coming not same like see my second screen shot you understand clearly.Sharpness is coming different

Comment: Check the `snippet`, i think the `corners` are same know. is that what you want ?

Comment: yes i want like this but little different is there. thikcness of the corner

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for you is to set `clear: both;` instead of `clear: right;`  in the CSS rules of `.userTextDiv` and of `.userTextDivOp`.

To solve the corner problem, just c/p the CSS of `.userTextDiv:before` and `after` to replace the CSS of `.userTextDivOp:before` and `after` and replace `right` rules by `left`.

Hope it helps.

```css
 .userTextDiv {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 4px;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDiv::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 right: -11px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDiv::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 right: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 8px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDiv img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.userTextDiv .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}

.userTextDiv .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 11px;
    clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 left: -11px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}


.userTextDivOp::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 left: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 8px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #8e0035;
}
```

```html
<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDiv">
  <div class="username">user</div>
  <span  class="message">click on oky button</span>
</div>

<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <div class="username">customer</div>
  <span class="message">helphelphelphelphelphelphelphehelphelphelphelphelphelplphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelphelp</span>
</div>
```